# Font not rendering properly / font-face not working?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I hope I'm asking this question in the right place,

I'm working on a website for a friend, here's the site hosted on my goDaddy acc:

http://www.andkensol.com/rowanWeb/

And here it is on my friends:

http://www.rowanmoore.org/

You can see the clear difference in the title font. If you inspect them you'll see they are both using CODE. I personally uploaded all the files myself and the file structure, layout, file paths are all identical yet the font won't render on my friends site.

I downloaded the font from font squirrel and I'm using @font face to implement it in both sites.

```
CSS

@font-face {
    font-family: CODE;
    src: url('font/CODE Light.otf');
}

#nameTitle{
    font-size:60px;
    font-family:CODE;
    color:white;
    font-weight:400;
    margin-bottom:-3%;
}
```

The 'font folder' is in the same folder as the stylesheet and CODE Light.otf is in the font folder.

Ive deleted the site from my friends server, downloaded it from mine and then uploaded it to my friends and still no luck.

Could this be a problem on goDaddy's end perhaps?

Comment: At least when I try opening the font file URL im my browser it gives a 404 error on the problematic one. On the working one Firefox gives me a download prompt for the file.

Comment: See if you can fix the error in the console. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: If all the paths are identical, maybe you put stuff in a `rowanWeb` subdirectory by mistake?

Comment: Cheers for the suggestions guys, very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use some webgenerator to generate css file with different formats of font.
I think your problem is wrong @font-face.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'nfs';
src: url('yourFont.eot');
src: url('yourFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('yourFont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('yourFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('yourFont.svg#yourFontName') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Diffrenet browser need other format to render and open font.

I'm using mostly those three webfont generators
http://onlinefontconverter.com/

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

http://convertfonts.com/

But there is more, type to uncle google "font generator"

**EDIT:** i think blank space in your font/CODE Light.otf is the problem try to use for example something like this font/CODE_Light.otf

Comment: whitespaces are no problem, when quoting the name of the font: `url('font/CODE Light.otf')`.

Comment: @Christoph so why when u write absolute url in browser it is not working at all? http://www.rowanmoore.org/css/font/CODE%20Light.otf  sometimes php got problem with blank spaces

Comment: You are right - I would not use file names which contain whitespaces either to avoid potential problems. In this case though I think it's not causing the OP's issues, but rather a access problem like I stated in my answer.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion Szymon

Comment: Finally got around to trying this and it works perfectly!! Cheers again Szymon!

Comment: @Daft glad I could help somehow :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a matter of access rights of your folders/files.

Something like `644` would be necessary for a file to be able to access the font from the outside web (the last 4 => read access for public). You can either use `chmod` on the console or change the rights in your ftp-client.

Also, you should support more than `otf`, or you will most likely lock out a significant amount of Internet Explorer Users.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christoph, in work right now so can't try this out but I will later on.